# Continuous functions on [0,1] are random variables

Tags: probability-theory

I am reading Knowing the odds by Walsh, there's one statement in the book

> Consider the probability space $([0,1],\mathcal B, P)$, where $\mathcal B$ is the Borel set and $P$ is Lebesgue measure.
>
> Let $g$ be a continuous function on $[0,1]$. Then $g$ is a random variable.

My question is, We know any continuous functions are Borel-functions and Borel function of a random variable is a random variable. Is the statement above means we regard $g$ as $g(X)$ where X is uniform in $[0,1]$?

Answer (score 0):

We can indeed do that.

If we will define $ \ X \ $ as $ \ X(\omega) \ := \ \omega \ $ for all $ \ \omega \in [0,1] \ $ then
$ \ X\sim \mathcal{U}[0,1] \ $ obviously.

Moreover, we can easily see that  sigma-field generated by $ \ X \ $ is equal to whole Borel sigma- field, i.e. $\ \sigma(X)=\mathcal{B}$.

Now note that $\ g=\mathbb{E}(g|\mathcal{B})=\mathbb{E}(g|\sigma(X))=\mathbb{E}(g|X)$,

and hence, there exist a Borel function $f$ such that $g=f(X)$.

[EDIT: And then we must have $g(\omega)=f(X(\omega))=f(\omega) \Longrightarrow g=f$]

All arguments above are due to basic properties of conditional expectation.